# How do I find the power law of divergence of second derivative of an integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation-theory

I have the integral of the following:

$$I(g) = g \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dk \sqrt{1+g^{-2} + 2g^{-1} \cos(k)},$$

whose second derivative ($\partial_g^2 I(g)$), I know diverges as $g \rightarrow 1$. How do I go about extracting the power law of this divergence, and what is the general bag of tricks to approximate integrals in certain limits like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the periodicity of the integrand
$$I(g)=g \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sqrt{1+g^{-2} + 2g^{-1} \cos(k)}\,dk=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+g^2 + 2g \cos(k)}\,dk$$
Then
$$J(g)=\frac{d^2}{dg^2}I(g)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dk}{\sqrt{1+g^2 + 2g \cos(k)}}-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(g+\cos k)^2}{\big(1+g^2 + 2g \cos(k)\big)^\frac32}dk=I_1+I_2$$
Second integral is regular at $g=1$, so we are focusing on the first one.
$$I_1=\frac{d^2}{dg^2}I(g)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dk}{\sqrt{(1-g)^2 + 2g (1+\cos(k))}}\overset{x=\frac k2}{=}4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-g)^2+4g\cos^2x}}$$
$$\overset{t=\tan x}{=}4\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}\sqrt{(1-g)^2(1+t^2)+4gt^2}}$$
$$\overset{t\to\frac1t}{=}\frac4{1+g}\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}\sqrt{t^2+\big(\frac{1-g}{1+g}\big)^2}}$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}\frac4{1+g}\frac{\ln\big(t+\sqrt{\big(\frac{1-g}{1+g}\big)^2+t^2}\,\big)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,\bigg|_{t=0}^\infty+\frac4{1+g}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\big(t+\sqrt{\big(\frac{1-g}{1+g}\big)^2+t^2}\big)}{(1+t^2)^\frac32}\,t\,dt$$
Second integral is regular at $g=1$; the first term gives us the desired singularity:
$$J(g)=\frac{d^2}{dg^2}I(g)=-2\ln(g-1)+O(1);\,\,g\to1^+$$

*Addendum*

As $\ln(g-1)$ is a slowly growing function, it might make sense to evaluate next asymptotic term $\sim O(1)$.
$$I_2=-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(g+\cos k)^2}{\big(1+g^2 + 2g \cos(k)\big)^\frac32}\,dk\sim-2^{-3/2}\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos k}\,dk=-2\tag{1}$$
The constant term in $I_1$
$$\frac4{1+g}\ln(1+g)+\frac4{1+g}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\big(t+\sqrt{\big(\frac{1-g}{1+g}\big)^2+t^2}\big)}{(1+t^2)^\frac32}\,t\,dt$$
$$\sim2\ln2+2\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(2t)}{(1+t^2)^\frac32}\,t\,dt=6\ln2\tag{2}$$
Using (1) and (2)
$$\boxed{\,\,J(g)=\frac{d^2}{dg^2}I(g)=-2\ln(g-1)+6\ln2-2+o(g-1);\,\,g\to1^+\,\,}$$